# Cannot read properties of undefined reading map error is coming

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets, nextjs

I write an smart contract for crowdfunding but when I try to fetch the event data from smart contract and  mapping the data this error is occur `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`Can anyone help me to fix this error.

**I also try this way but the same error occur**

```
const Page=({AllData})=>{
const [filter,setFilter]=useState([]);
const getAllcampaigns=()=>{
setFilter(AllData);
}
const allCampaignsData=()=>{
filter.map((e)=>console.log(e.title);
}
return(
<button onClick={()=>setFilter(AllData)>AllData</div>
<div>{filter.length>0?allCampaignData:null}</div>
)
}
```

Here is my Next Js Code

```
'use client'
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import campaignFactory from '../../artifacts/contracts/campaign.sol/campaignFactory.json';

const Page = ({ AllData }) => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(AllData);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setFilter(AllData)}>AllData</button>
      {filter.map((e) => (
        <p>{e.title}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page

export async function getStaticProps(){
  const provider=new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RPC_URL
  );
  const contract=new ethers.Contract(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ADDRESS,
    campaignFactory.abi,
    provider
  );
  const getAllCampaigns=contract.filters.campaignCreated();
  const AllCampaigns=await contract.queryFilter(getAllCampaigns);
  const AllData=AllCampaigns.map((e)=>{

    return{
      title:e.args.title
    }
  });
  return{
    props:{
      AllData
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my Smart Contract Code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity >0.8.0;

contract campaignFactory {
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;
    event campaignCreated(
        address indexed owner,
        string indexed category,
        uint256 indexed timestamp,
        string title,
        string imageUrl,
        address campaignAddress,
        uint256 requireAmount
    );

    function createCampaign(
        string memory campaignTitle,
        string memory storyUrl,
        uint requireAmount,
        string memory category,
        string memory imageUrl
    ) public {
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(
            campaignTitle,
            storyUrl,
            requireAmount,
            imageUrl,
            msg.sender
        );
        deployedCampaigns.push(address(newCampaign));
        emit campaignCreated(
            msg.sender,
            category,
            block.timestamp,
            campaignTitle,
            imageUrl,
            address(newCampaign),
            requireAmount
        );
    }
}

contract Campaign {
    event donated(address indexed donar, uint256 amount, uint256 timestamp);
    string public title;
    string public story;
    uint256 public requireAmount;
    string public imageUrl;
    address payable public owner;
    uint256 public receivedAmount;

    constructor(
        string memory _campaignTitle,
        string memory _story,
        uint256 _requireAmount,
        string memory _imageUrl,
        address campaignOwner
    ) {
        title = _campaignTitle;
        story = _story;
        requireAmount = _requireAmount;
        imageUrl = _imageUrl;
        owner = payable(campaignOwner);
    }

    function donate() public payable {
        require(requireAmount > receivedAmount, "Amount is fullfilled");
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
        receivedAmount += msg.value;
        emit donated(msg.sender, msg.value, block.timestamp);
    }
}
```

Comment: First console log the events and check if you are able to fetch the events or not. Sometimes the events are not fetched and we get this error.